# How to determine if a matrix is diagonalizable

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I'm studying for an algebra exam and one of the questions asked me if a matrix was diagonalizable.

Prior to this I has put the matrix in Jordan Form, which wasn't diagonal. Is a matrix only diagonalizable if it's Jordan Normal Form is diagonal?

Thank you for helping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes (at least if you work in an algebaically closed field such as $\Bbb C$).
This is a consequence of the fact that the JNF is unique and a diagonal matrix would be yet another JNF of your matrix.

Comment: I think it is unique up to reordering the Jordan blocks.

Comment: Thank to you so much for the help!